# JQuery $.get() on Java Servlet Not Working

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a Java Web Application that uses Servlets and JQuery. I use the $.get() method on a servlet that simply converts an object to JSON and writes it back. This used to work, but for some reason it no longer works. I've found in debug that the $.get() method doesn't get called at all, but the rest of the Javascript File is. It just skips the $.get() method altogether. I can't seem to figure out why, though. Here's my code:

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function () {

$.get('OrdersToJSONServlet', function (responseText) {
// ...I use responseText to populate Google Charts
}
```

The Java Servlet:

```
/**
 * <h1>Servlet implementation for converting order objects to JSON for use with JS</h1>
 */
@WebServlet("/OrdersToJSONServlet")
public class OrdersToJSONServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public OrdersToJSONServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param request
 * @param response
 * @throws javax.servlet.ServletException
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Object orders = request.getSession().getAttribute("orders");
    String json = new Gson().toJson(orders);
    try {
        response.getWriter().write(json);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("problem parsing JSON");
    }
}

}
```

I thought that maybe the annotation that is referenced by JQuery was somehow incorrect, but I'm not sure how or if that's the real problem. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Do you get any response if you simply hit the json link manually from browser?

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I'm much more of a Java developer than a web developer and this is my first web project. I suspect that what you are talking about is a feature of google developer tools that I might not know about. But if I use the javascript console and call $.get while simple printing the contents of responseText to the console, I get null. If I add a System.out.println to the servlet or use a breakpoint it is never called, supporting the assumption that $.get is never fired.

Comment: Don't take me wrong but I am saying is, what if you go to browser address bar and copy-paste the absolute url to the servlet and hit enter, and see if there is any error or you get desired response?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I actually found that I had a window.onload function in the file that, once removed, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

For others who are interested in this situation, I figured out the issue myself. The $.get method was located inside of window.onload. My Javascript was in an external file, and these two were not compatible. Silly mistake!